# How to change a attribute to a measure with DAX?

Tags: excel, attributes, powerpivot, dax

I have a lot of data in my database and I wish to display it as a Pivot Table using Power Pivot, however, some of my data is text (some flags, month names, names, last names, etc). Is there a way that I could convert these attributes to measure so the overall peformance of my Pivot table doesn't get affected?

I have some ideas but nothing clear yet, here is a sample of my table

```
UserID | Name | LName | City | State | QtySold
 1111    Jon    Smith    2      6       459394
 1112    Alex    Cash    6      2       31232
 1113    Rob    Adams    5      1       12434
```

I only need to use these attributes when I'm looking the data at UserID level (if I see the data at City, State leven It won't mather since I don't care about names / last names) is there a way I could evaluate the context and make the Name a measure?

Something like

```
=IF(UserID, DisplayLastName, BLANK())
```

(A new measure that checks if I'm using UserID, If I'm then display the LastName, If not, display blank)

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Oh well it seems that I found what I was looking for

```
LName:=IF(ISFILTERED(Details[UserID]),VALUES(Details[LName]),BLANK())
```

As long as UserID is on the Pivot Table, the LName measure will work.